# How to access the next blog post in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having some problems in building my React JS app. So, I have a blog, with posts, where each post have a detailed view. And from that detailed view i want two buttons, one which redirects the user to the next post and the other one redirects the user to the previous one. I have tried several ideas to make that happen but none of them actually worked. One more detail to say is that the posts are not one after each other, i mean one of them has id 12 and the next one has id 19.

Here`s a part of my code:

```
export default class DetailView extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

    const articleID = this.props.match.params.articleID;
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/${articleID}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            item: json,
        })
        });
}

render() {

    return(
        <div className="detailView font">
            blah blah, here the important part comes
                        <Row className="padding">
                            <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
                                <Button variant="outline-secondary"><Link to={''}>Previous project</Link></Button>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6} className="text-right">
                                <Button variant="outline-secondary"><Link to={''}>Next project</Link></Button>
                            </Col>  
                        </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide examples of what you've tried and add context e.g. what does your api respond with ?

Comment: I would, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the server, you could add an endpoint like `/posts/:id/next`, and then rather than the component needing to know what the next post ID is, the server will determine the next post (using post date, ID, really whatever works best for the design of your blog).